# Is the Pamir highway passable in early October?

Tags: safety, kyrgyzstan, dushanbe, central-asia, pamir-highway

A friend of mine is planning a trip through "the 'Stans" including the Pamir Highway but given its extreme altitude he is worried about whether it will be open or passable or safe at the beginning of October.

How early does the snow start at this height in this part of the world? Does the highway or part of it close during a certain period and if not is there a period where it's generally advised not to attempt it.

He intends to travel it by shared taxi.

Comment: In my opinion the Pamir Highway would be marginal at best. Saying that, we were not there in October.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this information](http://www.risk.ru/users/sromanenkov/15534/), in the winter of 2010/2011 the roads were open and were cleaned sometimes, but still it was in an awful condition:

[image]

Also you can easily stuck on the highway, if any avalanche happens, and wait for sometime anyone will clean it.

Comment: Sure looks like adventure travel though!

Answer (score 5):

Am in Tajikistan now and can tell you that even in summer there's snow at the top of the big peaks.  So I'd say it could easily surprise and come before October...

Shared taxi is the safest option in a landcruiser or similar, but hitching is another fun way to try it ;)

Comment: Hitchhiking it sounds great if it were for me but not sure about my friend (-: